# content provider able to do that? [android]

Tags: android

device A is user has Application I.

device B is user has Application I too.

device C is admin and will update the Application I data.

i am using sqlite and content provider to share data among them. Am i getting correct or wrong direction?

If wrong, please suggest me the correct way to implement it. Thanks

Comment: You mean, sharing data across different _physical_ devices?

Comment: @xandy: yup, just like facebook concept. admin at 1 location, then we all access to same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No content providers can't do that. Use Wifi [socket](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html) [communication](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html) to get this done.

Comment: @Reno: the sound like easy but it not really.

Comment: @Reno: after i read through, i still cannot get the concept. 
Is it create a class in the server application and a class in client application? 
But my idea is server application's database able to be access by client application so that when admin update latest, client able to retrieve it. 
Last but no least, if server application no on, the client application is able to retrieve the data?

Comment: Before you even make a database you need to have a communication protocol right?

Comment: @Reno: between 2 devices? Yup, its need but i forgot about this thing, i only remember use content provider to share the data, i thought it was from device to device. Server socket like a socket then client is plug. When both connected only can access the data in server application?

Comment: yes. Check how [remote droid](http://code.google.com/p/remotedroid/source/browse/trunk/RemoteDroid2.0/src/com/joshsera/DiscoverThread.java) does this.

Comment: @Reno: can give me a sample for "socket" and "plug" connection. I had a sample here [http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/] but seem like does not work. It always give me "could not get the connection" but my device already connected to wifi